# No se muestra la opcion de preview en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

El problema que tengo con android studio (primera vez que lo uso), es que no me sale la opcion para hacer una vista previa, es decir no me sale el celular que debe aparecer en la parte de la derecha, ya probe cambiando unos valores a esto:
  , poniendo Base antes de Theme pero tampoco ha funcionado. 
Quisiera saber si alguien sabe 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que seleccionar un layout (por ej content_main.xml). Para ver más layout, si es que los tiene el proyecto cambia de Project a Android (debajo de Holamundo), depliega la carpeta layout y selecciona un layout. Abajo de la ventana principal selecciona Design y listo o si dice Text, en la orilla derecha dice Gradle, haz click debajo en Preview

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, perdon por hacer este tipo de preguntas pero es que soy nuevo y ando aprendiendo, me ayudaste :)